# Postfix - disabled notifications for 535 5.7.8 Error: blocked

Tags: postfix, ndr

I have an anti-spam system based on 'postfix'.
When someone sends an email and is blocked by a blacklist, they get feedback.

Example below:

```
This is the mail system at host mail.xxx.com.

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

                   The mail system

<barbara@doris.herbert.lab.go4labs.net>: host
    doris.herbert.lab.go4labs.net[37.59.133.20] said: 535 5.7.8 Error: blocked
    by Block Address check from xx.xx.xx.xx (in reply to RCPT TO command)
```

Where can I disable 535 error notifications?

Comment: You accept the mail. But you don't want to do that.

Comment: I don't understand a bit of your comment.., Michael. I don't want to receive emails from specific addresses.
That's why a blacklist has been created, but also doesn't want to send them a notification that the mail has not arrived.

Comment: You can't control that. The notification comes from the other mail server, that tried and failed to deliver to you.

Comment: I understand. Could you send me an article or an RFC about this? I would like to know more about it.